# Count specific punctuation in a tag using Xpath

Tags: xpath, count, punctuation

I'm trying to count the amount of colon followed by space within tag "report":

`<report>But that doesn't work either: what do you guys think: To be solved</report>`

My xpath code

```
`report[count([text()=": "]) &gt; 1]`
```

but it not works

Comment: count(tokenize(/report/text(), ": "))-1

Comment: My actual XML file tag is
`<authors><author><gnm>Lee<gnm><snm>Auch<snm></author><report>Search Results: 
Count the number of words in a xml node using xsl: Thank you<report></authors>`

I tweaked your code as
`/report[count(tokenize(/text(), ': '))-1 gt 1]`

because i have to find more than one colon space usage within report tag.. but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the XPath 2.0 solution provided by @Slkrasnodar, here's the XPath 1.0 solution :

```
string-length(//report)-string-length(translate(//report,":",""))
```

We check the length of the original string. Then we generate a string without colon and check its length. Finally, we substract this length from the original length string to get the result.

Output : 2

EDIT : Please fix your XML file. It contains unclosed tags. I've worked with :

```
<authors>
<author>
<gnm>Lee</gnm>
<snm>Auch</snm>
</author>
<report>Search Results: Count the number of words in a xml node using xsl: Thank you</report>
</authors>
```

To get the authors names who have a report which contains more than one colon, use the following expression :

```
//authors[string-length(//report)-string-length(translate(//report,":",""))>1]//gnm/text()
```

Output : Lee

Comment: My actual XML file tag is

`<authors><author><gnm>Lee<gnm><snm>Auch<snm></author><report>Search Results: 
Count the number of words in a xml node using xsl: Thank you<report></authors>`

I tweaked your code as

`/authors[count(string-length(//report)-string-length(translate(//report,": ",""))) gt 1]`

because i have to find more than one colon space usage within report tag.. but it is not working

Comment: OK. I've posted a solution. Be careful, your xml is not valid.

Comment: Sorry modified by XML now, 

`<authors><author><gnm>Lee</gnm><snm>Auch</snm></author><report>Search Results: Count the number of words in a xml node using xsl: Thank you</report></authors>` 
can you help me now

Comment: I already did it. Didn't you read my edited answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61155195/9978746